# sed error - unterminated substitute pattern

Tags: sed

I am in directory with files consisting of many lines of lines like this:

```
98.684807 :(float)
52.244898 :(float)
46.439909 :(float)
```

and then a line that terminates:

```
[chuck]: cleaning up...
```

I am trying to eliminate `:(float)` from every file (but leave the number) and also remove that cleaning up... line.

I can get:

```
sed -ie 's/ :(float)//g' *
```

to work, but that creates files that keeps the old files. Removing the -e flag results in an unterminated substitute pattern error.

Same deal with:

```
sed -ie 's/[chuck]: cleaning up...//g' *
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What does "creates files that keeps the old files" mean?

Comment: If I have a file called abc. It removes the lines from file abc, but creates a file called abce.

Comment: The `g` is not necessary if the pattern only appears once per line.

Comment: I know I'm late, but `sed -ie 's/ :(float)//g' *` and `sed -ie 's/[chuck]: cleaning up...//g' *` will probably not do what you would expect; the `()` around `(float)`, the `[]` around `[float]`, and the `...` in `cleaning up...` are all special patterns. With `sed -ie 's/ :(float)//g' *`, it would probably match `:float` too. And with `sed -ie 's/[chuck]: cleaning up...//g' *`, it wouldn't match `[chuck]: cleaning up...` but would match `k: cleaning up123`.

Answer (score 16):

```
sed  -i  ''  -e  's/:(float)//'  -e  '/^.chuck/d'  *
```

This way you are telling sed not to save a copy (null length backup extention to `-i`) and separately specifying the sed commands.

Comment: For people getting the error "unterminated transform source string", this is effectively the answer as well. On some versions of sed (notably the BSD version, included with macOS), you must explicitly include the empty string `''` after the `-i` when you don't want sed to make a backup, on other platforms you can leave this out. The error messages that sed outputs when it's required and you don't leave it out are unfortunately rather cryptic.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution :**

`sed -i '' 's/ :(float)//g' *`

`sed -i '' 's/[chuck]: cleaning up...//g' *`

**Explanation :**

*I can get:*

```
sed -ie 's/ :(float)//g' *
```

*to work, but that creates files that keeps the old files.*

That's because `sed`'s `i` flag is supposed to work that way

> -i *extension*
>
> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified *extension*. If a zero-length *extension* is given, no backup will be saved.

In this case `e` is being interpreted as the *extension* you want to save your backups with. So all your original files will be backed up with an `e` appended to their names.

In order to provide a zero-length extension, you need to use `-i ''`.

**Note**: Unlike `-i<your extension>`, `-i''` won't work. You need to have a *space character* between `-i` and `''` in order for it to work.

---

*Removing the -e flag results in an unterminated substitute pattern error.*

When you remove the `e` immediately following `-i`, i.e.

`sed -i 's/ :(float)//g' *`

`s/ :(float)//g` will now be interpreted as the *extension* argument to `i` flag. And the first file in the list of files produced by shell expansion of `*` is interpreted as a sed `function` (most probably `s/regular expression/replacement/flags` function) You can verify this by checking the output of

`sedfn=$(echo * | cut -d' ' -f1); [[ ${sedfn:0:1} == "s" ]]; echo $?`

If the output of the above chain of commands is `0`, our assumption is validated.

Also in this case, if somehow the first filename qualifies as a valid `s/regular expression/replacement/flags` sed function, the other filenames will be interpreted as regular files for sed to operate on.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -ie expression [files...]
```

is equivalent to:

```
sed -ie -e expression [files...]
```

and both mean apply expression to files, overwriting the files, but saving the old files with an "e" as the backup suffix.

I think you want:
    sed -i -e expression [files...]

Now if you're getting an error from that there must be something wrong with your `expression`.

Answer (score 4):

your numbers are separated with `(float)` by the `:` character. Therefore, you can use awk/cut to get your numbers. Its simpler than a regex

```
$ head -n -1  file | awk -F":" '{print $1}'
98.684807
52.244898
46.439909

$ head -n -1  file | cut -d":" -f1
98.684807
52.244898
46.439909
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i -e 's/ :(float)//g' *
```

Comment: Could you kindly provide an explanation on this? 

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if you have any odd filenames in the directory.

Here is one way to duplicate your error:

```
$ touch -- "-e s:x:"
$ ls
-e s:x:
$ sed -i "s/ :(float)//g' *
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

One way to protect against this is to use a double dash to terminate the options to `sed` when you use a wild card:

```
$ sed -i "s/ :(float)//g' -- *
```

You can do the same thing to remove the file:

```
$ rm "-e s:x:"
rm: invalid option -- 'e'
$ rm -- "-e s:x:"
```